# Application Url vs Redirect Url

Tags: facebook, oauth, identity, facebook-oauth

We've an application called Mural.ly (https://mural.ly), our app has a Facebook Page (http://facebook.com/murallysocial).

We're using Singly (http://singly.com) to handle all our authentication magic, which is pretty similar to Auth0 (http://auth0.com) or Windows Azure Access Control.

Our problem is that when you click on the button for **Go to App**  it takes our users to http://api.singly.com which is the URL for normalizing and managing OAuth Tokens.

[image]

Is there any way you can change this URL (WebPage with Facebook Login) to be your app URL instead of OAuth redirectURL?

[image]

thanks in advance,

~johnny

Answer (score 1):

Singly creates special urls for all apps to avoid this problem.

Change your Site URL on facebook to:

```
 https://api.singly.com/auth/facebook/auth/SINGLY_APP_ID
```

Where SINGLY_APP_ID is your app's Singly client_id (which is public), and users visiting this link will be redirected to the URL you have configured for your Singly app.